# Control Reaches End Of Non Void Function for Void

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, void

Okay, I am trying to run a function in a different thread in c++. It takes no arguments and it is a void function. So when I see this warning saying:

```
warning: function declared 'noreturn' should not
  return [-Winvalid-noreturn]
```

I am surprised. I am using pthread for my threads. Here is the declaration of my function:

```
void* checkLogKext(void*);
```

And here is where I call my function:

```
pthread_t t1;
pthread_create(&t1, NULL, &checkLogKext, NULL);
```

And here is my function:

```
void* checkLogKext(void*) {
    ifstream logKext("/LogKextUninstall.command");
    if (logKext.is_open()) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: It isn't a void function : it returns something (and it takes an  argument) of type `void*`.

Comment: Oh and I got rid of the error by putting an infinite loop and a sleep in the function which I was originally going to do so I fixed it but I don't know how that works could someone please explain?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your return type is `void*` if you dont want to return anything it should be `void`. The same could be said about the argument you're taking for your function.

`void* foo(void*) // this takes a void* as paremeter and is expected to return one too`

`void foo(void) // doesn't return anything, and doesn't take any parameters either`

Comment: But for pthread doesn't the function have to be a pointer type?

Comment: @InsertNameHere I don't know what pthread expects, what I'm telling you is your return type is void* and so you are expected to return something.

Comment: @InsertNameHere pThread recommends using `pthread_exit(NULL);`, but I think `return NULL` should do just fine

Comment: @InsertNameHere If phtread requires the return type to be void* and you don't need to return anything you can just add `return NULL;`

Comment: So I suppose that the compiler recognized my infinite loop and realized that the function would keep running over and over and therefore not need to return anything. Thanks a lot for your help everyone

Answer (score 2):

Your function declaration says that it returns a void pointer, yet it doesn't do so in the code you show us, so the compiler warns you about that. Either change the declaration to

```
void checkLogKext(void*);
```

or actually return something. But I suppose what you meant to do is actually

```
void checkLogKext();
```

e.g. a function that doesn't take any parameters and doesn't return anything.